# Помогите разобраться с generic в функциях typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Всем привет. Я делаю один проект на react + typescript и хочу сделать функцию(ф1), которую можно вызвать, указав generic и аргумент-объект(о1), и получить другую функцию(ф2), которая возвращает объект(о2), составленный из некоторого поля объекта о1. И, я хочу, чтобы при вызове функции ф2 появлялись строковые подсказки, составленные из ключей того generic, который я передал при вызове ф1. Звучит немного запутанно, но, вроде, в коде все понятнее.

```
interface ErrorAndMessage {
    error: boolean;
    helperText: string | undefined;
}
type T1 = {[key: string]: any};
export function getMuiErrorAndMessageCreator1<T = T1> (errors: FieldErrors) {
return (field: keyof T):  ErrorAndMessage => {
    const message = errors[field]?.message;

    return {error: !!message, helperText: message};
}
}
```

Возникает такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом если создать функцию и вызвать ее, нужный функционал появляется.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `keyof` получает имена всех ключей, в твоем типе из-за индекса такого сделать нельзя

Comment: Дак а, не подскажите, можно ли как-то что-то переделать, чтобы оно заработало

Comment: не используй `T = T1`. Дополнительный вопрос, зачем тебе `T`, если обращаешься с этими полями ты в объект `errors`

Comment: Я изначально и указывал просто `Т`, оно тоже не работает. А указываю это `Т` я для того, чтобы потом указать тип `field` как `keyof T`, что, как я понимаю в итоге будет эквивалентно `field: 'title' | 'description' | ...`

Comment: почему не `keyof FieldErrors`?

Comment: ну, потому что, для контроля полей ввода я использую react-hook-form. После регистрации всех полей с именами `title, description, type, startDate, finishDate` я получаю доступ к различного рода состояниям этих полей ввода. В данный момент меня конкретно интересует объект с ошибками(неправильная длина текста и т.п.). И, получается, у меня есть интерфейс с описанными выше полями и для того, чтобы получать некоторые свойства для компонентов я и создал эту функцию. Указывать generic я хочу только для ого, чтобы были строки-подсказочки как на последней фотке в самом вопросе.

Comment: так используй `keyof FieldErrors` и будут те же самые подскзки

Comment: Ну, я вот попробовал сделать так, как вы мне сказали. Ошибок нет, как и подсказок((

Comment: сделай пример на https://www.typescriptlang.org/play чтобы было видно где какие типы у тебя есть и что ты с ними делаешь

Comment: Спасибо большое, что возился тут со мной) Я немного затупил с этим всем, а оказалось все просто

Answer (score 0):

В общем, я разобрался) Было немного глупо застрявать на этом так долго) Нужно было просто обернуть `field` в `String(field)`

```
interface ErrorAndMessage {
    error: boolean;
    helperText?: string;
}

export function getMuiErrorAndMessageCreator<T> (errors: FieldErrors) {
    return (field: keyof T, withoutHelperText = false):  ErrorAndMessage => {
        const res: ErrorAndMessage = {error: false};
        const message = errors[String(field)]?.message;

    res.error = !!message;
    if (!withoutHelperText) {
        res.helperText = message;
    }

    return res;
}
}
```

Comment: так и не понял, зачем тебе вообще `<T>` тут? Почему не использовать `FieldErrors`?

Comment: Ну, у меня есть интерфейс `CreateEventForm`, в котором содержаться те самые поля, которые должна содержать и потом вернуть форма. И, для того, чтобы не ошибиться в именах этих полей, когда я буду вызывать эту фукнцию, я передаю в нее в качестве `T` этот самый интерфейс, поля которого и используются потом для вызова. `const getErrorAndMessage = getMuiErrorAndMessageCreator<CreateEventForm>(errors);`. Потом происходит что-то вроде `getErrorAndMessage('title')`

Comment: Как ко всему этому относится `FieldErrors`?

Comment: `FieldErrors` - это просто тип объекта, который мне возвращает фукнция  useForm из библиотеки. Этот тип я указываю просто для того, чтобы не ошибиться при создании `getErrorAndMessage` и передать туда нужный объект.

Comment: Сейчас у тебя `T` никак не связан с `FieldErrors`, поэтому твои подсказки в принципе бесполезны, так как не гарантируют наличие такого поля в самом `FieldErrors`

Comment: Да, с этим согласен. Я там 2 раза указываю `generic`: для `useForm` и `getErrorAndMessageCreator`Вот ссылка на код, как это работает: https://github.com/DimaEff/itr_pet_front/blob/main/src/components/Map/AddEvent/AddEventForm.tsx#L35  ,  https://github.com/DimaEff/itr_pet_front/blob/main/src/utils/helper.tsx#L43

Comment: Бред какой-то... Приведи вопрос в порядок, тогда отвечу.